# $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] + href

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente código el que contiene **php_selft.** Cuando la  checkbox es marcada, este de inmediato me actualiza una informacion y la pagina, pero necesito que me direccione a una parte particular de la misma pagina así como como funciona el

```
<a href="#vista"></a>
 <A name="vista"></a>



 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="prueba">

        <input type="checkbox" name="identificacion" onclick="document.forms.prueba.submit()" value="<?php echo $data['cedula']?>">
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo lo que necesitas y de acuerdo a lo que necesitas, entonces intenta esto:

```
  //cambia el action por el id a donde lo quieres direccionar
 <form method="post" action="#vista" name="prueba">

    <input type="checkbox" name="identificacion" onclick="document.forms.prueba.submit()" value="<?php echo $data['cedula']?>">
```

/////////////////////////////

```
<a href="#vista">Aqui iral el check cuando sea presionado</a>
```

espero te sirva bro, me cuentas

Comment: me funciono perfecto gracias mil

Comment: De nada mi bro, siempre es un placer poder ayudar